# Event Sourcing in Mule

Tags: mule, event-sourcing

Could anyone guide me how to do event sourcing in mule as mentioned in the blog below
https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-event-sourcing

Answer (score 0):

The article describes a conceptual practice. You can implement it as you like. It is not something that Mule provides. It is the same as you would design your database as an example. Not a Mule concept.